# как добавить русскую локаль в проект xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Использую pod CVCalendar в проекте и мне нужно,чтобы календарь был на русском языке ( дни недели, месяц). Посмотрел в настройках - ничего не нашел.Как добавить русскую локаль в проект xcode?

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вам надо найти, где в CVCalendar находится NSDateFormatter и у него в свойстве locale поставить что вам надо

Comment: Получилось через свойство, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В картинках:

1,2,3:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выбираете нужную из списка

Comment: так получалось в xcodeproject , а в xcworkspace таких настроек не вижу...

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял, то вам надо найти, где в CVCalendar находится NSDateFormatter и у него в свойстве locale поставить что вам надо